# Denodo Virtual Dataport Admin Server not opening on Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, denodo

We have a machine - Windows Server 64 bit in MS Azure Cloud, where we have installed Denodo 5.5 full package with license.

The VM has two IPs, one being Internet IP by which we connect the VM and one Internal IP.

We have made changes in the Virtual Dataport >> JVM options >> RMI Host to reflect External IP in the Hostname.

We tried restarting the Virtual Dataport Server and VM multiple times. We also ensured that the above RMI configuration has been successfully saved in the Denodo configuration files.

Yet we are unable to open up the Denodo Virtual Dataport Admin Server from network machines (in internet) using the external IP. The firewall is also turned off in the Azure VM.

Please help resolve this issue if you have any idea on this one.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned "We have made changes in the Virtual Dataport >> JVM options >> RMI Host to reflect External IP in the Hostname." but in this case you need to use the Internal IP so Denodo knows what network interface it needs to use. You can find more information in the following link https://community.denodo.com/kb/view/document/Installation%20steps%20on%20a%20cloud%20environment?category=Installation+%26+Updates